# Autodesk view-and-data load the Extension Material error

Tags: javascript, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

When I loaded the Material extension, like this:
[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

But failed~
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

More details : 
[issue_link](https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/view-and-data-npm/issues/9)

Comment: can you review your question? It's missing the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) script reference in your html in order to use the "require" function in that extension